# How do I set up an if statement to use an array of conditionals as input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

First I check a given condition, as per a normal `IF` statement. If it is `True`, I need to scan all files for a single keyword. If it is not `True`, I need to scan all files for a set of keywords, which will have been supplied.

For my simple working example, rather than scanning file names in a directory, I simply search a string for the keywords.

```
test1 = "NotKeyWord"
password = "password"
password1 = "password1"
password2 = "password2"
password3 = "password3"

if test1.lower() == "keyword":
    condition = password
else:
    condition = [password1, password2, password3]

f = "password1_password2_password3_jibberish_E=mc2"
if condition in f:
    print("Problem solved")
```

If the keyword = "keyword" i.e., is singular, then this code works. Fine. However, I would like to make it so that if it is the other case, which requires knowing several keywords to grab the right file, I don't need to resort to explicitly writing out all the words.

For my purposes I could write

```
if password1 in f and password2 in f and password3 in f:
    print("problem solved")
```

But I am after a pythonic method, that will hopefully be generic enough to be able to handle an array of keywords that is of unknown length, and thus can't be hard coded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work,

```
if all ( c in f for c in condition ):
    print("problem solved")
```

Comment: The problem here is that if any of them are true, it passes, but I need ALL of them to be true

Comment: Okay, you can change to the condition to all(). I have edited it

Answer (score 3):

Make `condition` always be a list, even if it only has one item:

```
if test1.lower() == "keyword":
    condition = [password]
else:
    condition = [password1, password2, password3]
```

Then use the `all()` function to check if all elements in `condition` are present in f:

```
if all(c in f for c in condition):
    print("problem solved")
```

This will work whether `condition` has one element, or ten, or a hundred.

Comment: amen. I will flip a coin to see who gets it since Nebiyou had it too, just with the "any" rather than "all"

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
if [x for x in condition if x in f]:
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier for yourself, I would make a list of passwords in both cases. If test1 is the keyword then it just becomes a list of one.

```
if test1.lower() == "keyword":
    passwords = [password]
else:
    passwords = [password1, password2, password3]
```

Then you can use Python's built-in [all function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with a [generator expression](https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions) for the second condition.

```
f = "password1_password2_password3_jibberish_E=mc2"
if all(pw in f for pw in passwords):
    print("Problem solved")
```